# A proposition about filters on cartesian product of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

I call *reloid* a filter on a cartesian product of two sets.

I define *product* $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$ of two filters $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ as the reloid generated by the filter base $\{ A\times B \,|\, A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B} \}$.

Please help to prove:

$\bigcap\{ \mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B} \,|\, B\in T \} = \mathcal{A}\times\bigcap T$ for every filter $\mathcal{A}$ and set $T$ of filters.

I need this to finish the proof that product of filters (with left argument being a fixed filter) is an (antitone) lattice homomorphism. I further need this to prove that certain categories are cartesian closed. Well, this is an other story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Counter-example:

Let $\uparrow A$ be the principal filter on $\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to the set $A$. Let $[X]$ is the filter induced by the base $X$.

Let $\Delta = [\{ (-e;e) \,|\, e\in\mathbb{R}, e>0 \}]$.

For a counter-example take $\mathcal{A}=\Delta$ and $T=\{\uparrow\{x\} \,|\, x\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Then $\bigcap T=\uparrow\mathbb{R}$ and thus $\mathcal{A}\times\bigcap T = \Delta\times\uparrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\bigcap\{ \mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B} \,|\, B\in T \} = \bigcap\{ \Delta\times\uparrow\{x\} \,|\, x\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Take $K = \bigcup \left\{ \{ x \} \times ( - 1 / x ; 1 / x) \,|\, x \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$. Then it's easy to prove

$K \in \bigcap\{ \Delta\times\uparrow\{x\} \,|\, x\in\mathbb{R} \}$ but $K\notin \Delta\times\uparrow\mathbb{R}$.